# Form validation issues with CakePHP

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 2.3.8 and trying to validate an image upload with CakePHP but Cake is giving me trouble with the validation. I know the validation is being triggered because if I remove the specific extension from the validation rules, I then receive a validation error message. (EX: remove 'jpg' from the validation list and I upload a .jpg file it then shows the error message).

```
'image' => array(
    'extension' => array(
        'rule' => array('extension', array('png','jpg','jpeg', 'gif')),
              'message' => 'Only jpeg, png and gif images are supported',
        )
),
```

Here's what I have in my controller

```
if($this->request->is('post')){
    $this->Setting->set($this->request->data);
    if($this->Setting->validates() == true){
        $this->Session->setFlash('success');    
    }
    else{
        $this->Session->setFlash('fail');
    }
}
```

If I upload, say image2.jpg I get the 'fail' message but I **don't** get a validation message. If I remove '.jpg' from the extensions list and upload a jpg file, I then get the 'fail' message and the validation error message.

When I debug this->request->data I get the following response

```
array(
'Setting' => array(
    'id' => '5', //hidden field
    'current_image' => '2_52547d56-1d80-410e-b739-09cecbdd56cb', //hidden field
    'image' => array(
        'name' => 'IMG_4385.JPG',
        'type' => 'image/jpeg',
        'tmp_name' => '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpilL54j',
        'error' => (int) 0,
        'size' => (int) 1608456
    )
)
)
```

As I stated, when I remove the jpg extension from the validation rules, the message shows. I know it's probably "finding" the image in the posted data.

**Edit - I figured out the problem**

The view I'm working with has 2 forms. One for submitting images, and one for text input. In the Setting model I have validation for the text inputs and the image. Despite being completely separate forms it appears that it was trying to validate those text inputs but it wasn't receiving any information for them in the sent data. I changed the validation call to only validate the image and it worked

```
if($this->Setting->validates(array('fieldList' => array('image'))) == true){...
```

Comment: What is the version of cakephp?

Comment: Sorry, it's 2.3.8. I'll add that to my post

Comment: Ok. I'v posted an awnser. If it doesn't work, pls post your `debug($this->request->data)`

Comment: Check possible other validation errors: `debug($this->Session->validationErrors)`.

Comment: @ndm debugging the validation errors returns null

Comment: Then there's something weird going on, in any case it should be an array (as far as I can tell). Try with a clean installation and only that single validation rule.

Comment: @ndm I got it to work. Please see my updated post above if you'd like to see what was happening.

Comment: If you figured out the problem please _answer your own question_ and _accept the answer_. A question with the "answer" in the question is still considered/treated as an unanswered question by stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. Thanks for your tips anyway.

The view I'm working with has 2 forms. One for submitting images, and one for text input. In the Setting model I have validation for the text inputs and the image. Despite being completely separate forms it appears that it was trying to validate those text inputs but it wasn't receiving any information for them in the sent data. I changed the validation call to only validate the image and it worked

```
if($this->Setting->validates(array('fieldList' => array('image'))) == true){
    //do stuff
}
```