# Security salt issues with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I had some form validation issues which I created [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613459/form-validation-issues-with-cakephp). Someone suggested starting with a fresh installation of Cake, so I decided to replace the lib folder with a fresh copy and keep my app folder.

I renamed the original lib folder to lib1 rather than deleting it and dragged in a fresh copy of the lib folder. Upon trying to open my app I got the message to change the security salt. `Please change the value of 'Security.salt' in APP/Config/core.php to a salt value specific to your application. [CORE/Cake/Utility/Debugger.php, line 849]`

I changed the salt value and it went away, but then when I tried to login to an account on my application, it says invalid password. I changed the salt back to the original version and put back the original lib folder and I could once again log in.

Is there any way that I can get this to work, or will I have to start with an entirely fresh copy and transfer all of my current models, views, js files, etc..? If the salt is located in the app folder and that's the only location you have to modify it upon initial installation, what is it about the lib folder that it recognizes the salt is incorrect?

Comment: When you 'changed the salt value', did you change it to the same as the previous salt when you first set up your user account?

Comment: @Dave I'm not sure what you mean. The security salt is located in the app folder which was not changed. When I dumped in the new lib folder it gave me errors about the salt needing to be changed. Upon changing it I then had the issue of not being able to log into any accounts.

Comment: if you've created your application with the default salt - that was a mistake. If you need to change the salt existing hashed values (passwords) will not be usable.

Comment: @AD7six Oh ok, you meant the initial creation. I definitely changed the salt upon creating the application. Thanks for the clarificatio

Comment: If you're getting that warning - that seems unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create users using the new `salt`.

You aren't supposed to use the default salt.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to database you can change your password by concatenating your SALT value from core with your plain desired password and do SHA1 of this string.

Ex:

```
Salt = 9Fv2a6h392t8ST4L46850151C156PeR7
Pass = test
```

Encrypted database password:

```
sha1(9Fv2a6h392t8ST4L46850151C156PeR7test) = 3ef431e19c03c3d9878ecb8a743a706d54e6662c
```